# Query database within wordpress plugin

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a plugin and I need to query a custom table within the wordpress database, I am using this code but it outputs nothing.

```html
/**
 * Plugin Name: My Plugin
 * Plugin URI: http://www.domian.com
 * Description: Complete engine for www.mydomian.com
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Bradley Fletcher
 * Author URI: http://www.domian.net
 * License: GPL2
 */
 
add_action('admin_menu', 'mrq');

function mrq() {
 
 add_menu_page('Partners', 'My Removals Quote', 'administrator', 'my-plugin-settings', 'mrq_settings_page', 'dashicons-admin-generic', '21', 'myremovalsquote');
}

function mrq_settings_page() {

 if (is_user_logged_in()) {

  global $wpdb;
  $customers = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT partner_id, partner_name, email_address, active FROM partners WHERE active ='yes' ORDER BY partner_id ASC");

  echo "<table>";
  
  foreach($customers as $customer) {

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$customer->partner_id."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$customer->partner_name."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
  }

  echo "</table>";
 
 } else {
 
  echo "Sorry, only registered users can view this information";
 
 }
}
```

Comment: is there any records in your database?

Comment: fml... I forgot that i cleared the entries! sometimes you have to think outside the box! thank you!